# Does `make savedefconfig` lose configuration options?

Tags: linux-kernel, configuration, kernel-modules

I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong here. I was under the impression that `make savedefconfig` would be the way to go to reduce one config to the (equivalent) bare minimum.

So here are my step, take a config file from the Debian package directly:

```
$ dpkg -S /boot/config-4.14.0-3-powerpc
linux-image-4.14.0-3-powerpc: /boot/config-4.14.0-3-powerpc
$ apt-cache policy linux-image-4.14.0-3-powerpc
linux-image-4.14.0-3-powerpc:
  Installed: 4.14.13-1
  Candidate: 4.14.13-1
  Version table:
 *** 4.14.13-1 500
        500 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian sid/main powerpc Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Copy it over to my main machine:

```
$ scp macminig4:/boot/config-4.14.0-3-powerpc ./arch/powerpc/configs/my_defconfig
```

Verify the option I want to play with is still there:

```
$ grep CONFIG_SSB_B43_PCI_BRIDGE ./arch/powerpc/configs/my_defconfig
CONFIG_SSB_B43_PCI_BRIDGE=y
```

Now let's update it since it is not in perfect sync with git v4.14:

```
$ git checkout v4.14
$ make ARCH=powerpc my_defconfig
$ diff -u .config ./arch/powerpc/configs/my_defconfig | diffstat
 my_defconfig |    8 ++++----
 1 file changed, 4 insertions(+), 4 deletions(-)
```

So some minor change occurred, but nothing bad, at least I can still see my option:

```
$ grep CONFIG_SSB_B43_PCI_BRIDGE .config
CONFIG_SSB_B43_PCI_BRIDGE=y
```

Now let's try a savedefconfig:

```
$ make ARCH=powerpc savedefconfig
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/bin2c
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/conf.o
  SHIPPED scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.c
  SHIPPED scripts/kconfig/zconf.lex.c
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
scripts/kconfig/conf  --savedefconfig=defconfig Kconfig
```

If I now check my option is now lost forever:

```
$ grep CONFIG_SSB_B43_PCI_BRIDGE defconfig 
-> nothing !
```

Why are some options disappearing? Is there a way to control `savedefconfig` to preserver some option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this was simply bad timing. The git/master (actually 4.15) is affected by:

- https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/10185397/

> After upgrading an old laptop to 4.15-rc9, I found that the eth0 and
>   wlan0 interfaces had disappeared.  It turns out that the b43 and b44
>   drivers require SSB_PCIHOST_POSSIBLE which depends on
>   PCI_DRIVERS_LEGACY, a config option that only exists on Mips.